# About divs position

Tags: css

i have this  three divs i just want to know how to position multiple divs in div :

```
<div id="myDIV" >
    <div id="child">
    </div>
<div id="child2">
    </div>
</div>

div#myDIV
{
position:relative;
width:300px;
height:300px;
background:red;
left:10px;
top:100px;
}

div#child
{
position:relative;
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:blue;
left:10px;
top:10px;
}

div#child2
{
position:relative;
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:yellow;
left:150px;
top:10px;
}

   http://jsfiddle.net/ynw5d/
```

why yellow div is not top:10 like blue div?

And what is better for using : position relative or margins for working with divs.

Comment: You want them to overlap?

Comment: i think yes , from bottom of red div

Comment: Please give us an illustration (a screenshot, perhaps?) of the requested situation.

Comment: Please try not to use `&nbsp;` for layout purposes. Its size depends on the font and is not a reliable way to format your page in general.

Comment: @adenoyelle Yes from what I understand he wants half of the blue div outside the red one and the other half inside.

Comment: something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/s9Kqd/ ? (I put some opacity to see the overlap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think he want this

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NwSU4/

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
   <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer{
    background-color: red;
    margin:100px;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    position: relative;
}

.inner{
    background-color: blue;
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: I want to upvote this, but I have no clue whether it is the correct answer or not, as the question is still quite vague.

Comment: +1 for understanding that English and put this solution :)

Comment: ye i am not sure too if it is what he want but from this sentence "Basicly blue div is 100px Height , 50px in red div and 50 px up from red div" i think it is. maybe its becouse my english is not good too, so we have some kind of understanding